# How to force a failure with phpunit

Tags: phpunit

Is there a more official way to force a phpunit failure than `$this->assertTrue(false)`?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I believe this should work within a test case:

```
$this->fail('Message');
```

Comment: The $this->fail() will stop the execution of the test, so this shouldn't be used as a replacement to assertions to display a message if you have multiple assertions in your test.

Comment: Passing an exception to `fail` will result in a nice stacktrace

Comment: is there an opposite function of `$this->fail()`?

Comment: @emfi - yes, ````return;````.

Comment: If you just `return;`, you will probably also need the `@doesNotPerformAssertions` annotation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, theres a way,

```
$this->fail("your message");
```

if you want to see the page u have failed than

```
print_r(getResponse()->getContent());
```

Comment: `getResponse()` is a framework specific function, which may not be generally available.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it (especially helpful when writing a testing tool) would be:

```
use PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException as PHPUnitException;

try {
    // something here
} catch (SpecificException $e) {
    // force a fail:
    throw new PHPUnitException("This was not expected.");
}
```